# Real integral getting numerically evalued to complex number

Tags: definite-integrals, wolfram-alpha

I tried feeding th following integral into WolframAlpha:

$$\int_0^2\frac{1}{3\sqrt{x}(\log(x))^{\frac13}},$$

to get an idea of its value. Result:

> http://bit.ly/strangeint
>
> $$\int_0^2\frac{1}{3\sqrt{x}(\log(x))^{\frac13}}=0.810563-0.620515.$$

And I'm like "How exactly could a real integral have a complex value?". No seriously, the integrand is real for all real values, so how did that complex part come about?

Comment: I think it's taking into account other values of $\sqrt[3]{\log x}$ (when $0<x<1$).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

WolframAlpha distinguishes between `x^(1/3)` and `cbrt(x)` - the first returns the *principal* root while the second returns the *real* root.  For example, `cbrt(-8)` returns $-2$ while `(-8)^(1/3)` returns $1 + 1.73205i$.  Thus, you can use `cbrt` in your WolframAlpha query.

```
integrate (1/(3*sqrt(x)*cbrt(log(x))), x=0..2)
```

[image]

Note that the output states that the computation assumes that `cbrt` is the real root and offers you a button to switch to the principal.  Your computation with `log(x)^(1/3)` should have assumed the principal and offered a button to get to the real.

Comment: I think it did, but I had no idea what it meant :).

Comment: (+1) instructive answer, I did not know such feature.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the logarithm has a branch point in $0$, as well as $\sqrt[3]{z}$, so we must be careful when defining the branches we are taking. If we simply set $x=e^t$ we have:
$$ I = \int_{-\infty}^{\log 2}\frac{e^{t/2}}{3 t^{1/3}}\,dt = \int_{0}^{\log 2}3t^{-1/3}e^{t/2}\,dt+\int_{-\infty}^{0}3t^{-1/3}e^{t/2}\,dt$$
where the first integral can be computed through a Taylor series and the second one depends on a value for the $\Gamma$ function, *once* we define $t^{-1/3}$ for $t<0$ as $-(-t)^{-1/3}$. Wolfram Alpha is unaware of such assumption, so it probably takes another branch, resulting in a complex-valued integral.

Comment: Is there a way to tell Wolfram of the assumption, and get the correct real value?